# Linq query generator tools

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to know is there any tool like Sql Query Editor for LINQ. So that the Linq and Lambda expressions will be generated easily.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

http://www.linqpad.net/ is also great

Answer (score 1):

I would also add [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net)

Answer (score -1):

Give this one a try.  I think it's better than LinqPad:

[CentralLinqMvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CentralLinqMvc/)