# where can I find a good example of using linq & lambda expressions to generate dynamic where and orderby sql?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, dynamic-sql

where can I find a good example of using linq & lambda expressions to generate dynamic sql?
For example, I need a method to take these parameters

```
GoupOperator ('And' or 'OR')
A list of objects each with the following parameters:
    SearchColumn.
    SearchValue.
    SearchOperator (equals, contains, does not equal ...)
```

And another method to orderby any particular column ascending or descending

If this question has been properly answered before , I will gladly delete it - none of previous answers Ive seen are comprehensive enough for a person new to linq expressions to plug into an existing application with little trouble --thanks

Comment: Why making a method for that? Use linq+lambda whenever you need it directly. To get all books with title of 3-6 characters with either a space or a dash, ordered by the author name: books.Where(book => book.Title.Length <= 6 && book.Title.Length >= 3 && (book.Title.Contains(" ") || s.Contains("-"))).OrderBy(book.Author)

Comment: Making a method for dynamic linqing will be very messy if you want it perfect, and the code outside that uses the method will be uglier than just doing the specific linq. Don't over-kill generalization.

Comment: @YoryeNathan I want to avoid specifying search parameters at this level - I have way too many columns and search conditions

Comment: You will specify the search terms in this level either way - to the linq or to your linqing method. Edit in a linq that you find ugly to give us more information of your situation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179806/linq-query-generator-tools

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a couple of linq extension methods (generic Where and OrderBy methods written by Ilya Builuk that take the columnname, search value and search operations plus a grouping operator) on codeproject [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58357/Using-jqGrid-s-search-toolbar-with-multiple-filter) that shows how to do this using asp.net mvc.
the methods construct a dynamic expression tree -very elegant solution.
Since I had started using a traditional asmx web service, I used his helpers in my project and just made a few changes to get it running  [here](http://kodesnippetsnstuff.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/jqgrid-traditional-asmx-webservice-multiple-search-sorting-using-custom-linq-extension-methods/) -

Here are the 2 methods

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    /// <summary>Orders the sequence by specific column and direction.</summary>
    /// <param name="query">The query.</param>
    /// <param name="sortColumn">The sort column.</param>
    /// <param name="ascending">if set to true [ascending].</param>
    public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string sortColumn, string direction)
    {
        string methodName = string.Format("OrderBy{0}",
            direction.ToLower() == "asc" ? "" : "descending");

        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "p");

        MemberExpression memberAccess = null;
        foreach (var property in sortColumn.Split('.'))
            memberAccess = MemberExpression.Property
               (memberAccess ?? (parameter as Expression), property);

        LambdaExpression orderByLambda = Expression.Lambda(memberAccess, parameter);

        MethodCallExpression result = Expression.Call(
                  typeof(Queryable),
                  methodName,
                  new[] { query.ElementType, memberAccess.Type },
                  query.Expression,
                  Expression.Quote(orderByLambda));

        return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(result);
    }


    public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> query,
        string column, object value, WhereOperation operation)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(column))
            return query;

        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "p");

        MemberExpression memberAccess = null;
        foreach (var property in column.Split('.'))
            memberAccess = MemberExpression.Property
               (memberAccess ?? (parameter as Expression), property);

        //change param value type
        //necessary to getting bool from string
        ConstantExpression filter = Expression.Constant
            (
                Convert.ChangeType(value, memberAccess.Type)
            );

        //switch operation
        Expression condition = null;
        LambdaExpression lambda = null;
        switch (operation)
        {
            //equal ==
            case WhereOperation.Equal:
                condition = Expression.Equal(memberAccess, filter);
                lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
                break;
            //not equal !=
            case WhereOperation.NotEqual:
                condition = Expression.NotEqual(memberAccess, filter);
                lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
                break;
            //string.Contains()
            case WhereOperation.Contains:
                condition = Expression.Call(memberAccess,
                    typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"),
                    Expression.Constant(value));
                lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
                break;
        }


        MethodCallExpression result = Expression.Call(
               typeof(Queryable), "Where",
               new[] { query.ElementType },
               query.Expression,
               lambda);

        return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(result);
    }
}
```

Below is how I used these methods, the return object is simply a custom object that supplies data to a client side grid

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public JgGrid SearchGrid(int rows, int page, string sidx, string sord,string filters)
    {
        AdvWorksDataContext dc = new AdvWorksDataContext();
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        filters f = serializer.Deserialize<filters>(filters);

        var p = dc.vProductAndDescriptions.AsQueryable();
        if (f.groupOp == "AND")
            foreach (var rule in f.rules)
                p = p.Where<vProductAndDescription>(
                    rule.field, rule.data,
                    (WhereOperation)StringEnum.Parse(typeof(WhereOperation), rule.op)
                    );
        else
        { 
            //Or
            var temp = (new List<vProductAndDescription>()).AsQueryable();
            foreach (var rule in f.rules)
            {
                var t = p.Where<vProductAndDescription>(
                    rule.field, rule.data,
                    (WhereOperation)StringEnum.Parse(typeof(WhereOperation), rule.op)
                    );
                temp = temp.Concat<vProductAndDescription>(t);
            }
            p = temp;
        }
        p = p.OrderBy<vProductAndDescription>(sidx, sord);

        return new JgGrid(page, p, rows);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I make this case insensitive? Currently sorts A, B, C, a.

Comment: I'd have to add a new parameter "new CaseInsensitiveComparer()" to the call to OrderBy

Comment: let me know if this works - I havent tried it out - swap the OrderBy method with the one here http://codeshare.io/dNp13

Comment: What is the correct way to use it?  var list = objectContext.DEALER.Include("DEALER_TYPE_CAT").Include("DEALER_TYPE_EQP")
                            .Include("DEALER_SERVICE_AREA").AsQueryable().OrderBy<DEALER>(sortExpression, sortDirection);

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No generic method 'OrderBy' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

Answer (score 1):

For cases where I have many columns that need dynamic query composition I use Dynamic Linq. This is a library written as an example for .net 3.5 and it illustrates how you can write linq extensions that operate on the expression tree.

It can also be used for composing dynamic queries based on strings received from the client, such as column names, sorting, etc.

Here's a link a to an article posted by Scott Guthrie
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

In the article you will find the links to the examples library which contains the source code for the Dynamic Linq library.

Comment: I prefer not to use dynamic linq - as I would still have to specify all search parameters rather than allow a client side app to generate them - plus my client app generates the filter and orders by paramaters in the form I have in the questions - loopin over these and converting these to dynamic linq seems messy to me

Comment: I'm not sure why using dynamic linq would be messy. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I intend this to serve data to a client side grid. Thers are possibly Variable number of search filters each with one of several possible search operators...how can I create all combinations of filters and operators using dynamic linq?maybe I just need to see a fully worked out example

Comment: see the solution I went for above

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're trying to build a linq provider...
Try to check this tutorial serie on how to implement a custom Linq to SQL provider :  [LINQ: Building an IQueryable provider series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx)

Comment: see the solution I settled for above - for my needs I did not need to write a provider