# Generic List Object OrderBy dynamic Column name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, sorting

I am trying to sort data which is from `Generic List` object.
By using below code, I can sort my data according to `Title` column.
But what I would like to do is I would like to sort data according to parameter value called `sidx`.

```
public ActionResult ListingGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        int currentPage = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int totalRecords = 0;
        var SeminarList = (List<Seminar>)null;

        if(sord.Equals("asc"))
            SeminarList = seminarRepository.AllSeminarList().Seminar_Masters
                  .OrderBy(x => x.Title )
                  .Skip(currentPage * rows)
                  .Take(rows)
                  .ToList();
        else
            SeminarList = seminarRepository.AllSeminarList().Seminar_Masters
                  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Title)
                  .Skip(currentPage * rows)
                  .Take(rows)
                  .ToList();

        totalRecords = seminarRepository.AllSeminarList().Seminar_Masters.Count;

        var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)rows);

        ....
    }
```

So I have modified my code like that, but it does not work.
It does not sort as I have expected.

```
SeminarList = seminarRepository.AllSeminarList().Seminar_Masters
                  .OrderBy(x => sidx)
                  .Skip(currentPage * rows)
                  .Take(rows)
                  .ToList();
```

The object which I now use is pure `List` object, not `IQueryable` object.

As for sorting purpose, I don't want to go back to `SQL select statement`, I would like to sort data at Controller layer.

Please let me get any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See answer for dynamic where and orderby using some helper
methods here
 [where can I find a good example of using linq & lambda expressions to generate dynamic where and orderby sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801116/where-can-i-find-a-good-example-of-using-linq-lambda-expressions-to-generate-d)

Answer (score 2):

You must order by a column that is in your result set. If the sidx is not part of your resultset then it is like ordering by a constant. Thus every row will be the same and it will not REALLY be ordered. Let's assume sidx's value is 10, then it would be like ordering this resultset:

```
Row 1 | 10
Row 2 | 10
Row 3 | 10
...
```

You can see how the ordering would be pointless

What you need to do is add sidx to your result set if that is what you want:

```
SeminarList = seminarRepository.AllSeminarList().Seminar_Masters
                  .OrderBy(x => x.sidx)
                  .Skip(currentPage * rows)
                  .Take(rows)
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

So you're saying that the calling method will provide a Property name via the `sidx` parameter, and you want to sort by that property?

The easiest way is to use the [Dynamic LINQ library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). Another option would be to use reflection to find the property you're looking for, then build a lambda expression from it.